# t's changed to "ti" when exporting to PDF

Tags: crystal-reports

My Crystal report generates this text:

```
This is to certify that {FullName} has completed the course
```

where the formula `{Fullname}` is: `Mr. + Name`

I want to change `{FullName}` to remove the title "Mr". I used Find in Formulas on `{FullName}` and changed the Display String from `Mr. + {?FullName}` to `{?FullName}`.  But somehow this replaced every lowercase "t" with "ti". So now the static string is changed to:

```
This is tio certify tihati .... has successfully completied tihe course
```

How can I correct this? A key note is that this only happens when exporting to PDF. In the Main Report Preview, the report displays correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is a [*really weird bug*](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1272660) involving the Calibri font. Certain glyphs aren't handled correctly when exporting to PDF. The solutions I've found are as follows:

> **A)** Avoid using Calibri fonts in Crystal Reports.  You might try a more
>   common True Type font, such as Arial.  Again, be sure that font is
>   installed on every... workstation.
>
> or
>
> **B)** Downgrade Crystal Reports to use a legacy Microsoft Uniscribe
>   component (*USP10.dll*).  Here’s the procedure that we’ve used at
>   Alterity with good results.

Here are  advanced instructions for [*Solution B*](https://help.acctivate.com/articles/18812/), but I'd just recommend changing fonts. I'm sure you can find one very close to Calibri without this issue.

Comment: I chased this error some time ago too. Do you know if it is limited to specific (CR/Windows) versions?

Comment: @dd4711 I know it was an issue for the built-in Crystal Report editor for VS 2005, (and obviously whatever version aggelos is using.) But it's either been fixed or I haven't noticed it in VS2015 or standalone Crystal 2013